# How to pass reflector to Nest.js global guard?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, guard

I am new to nest.js and I have a question.
I have a Roles Guard like this

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
    if (!roles) {
      return true;
    }
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;
    return user.role.some(role => !!roles.find(item => item === role));
  }

}
```

Now I want to use this guard as a global guard  like this

```
app.useGlobalGuards(new RolesGuard())
```

But it says that I need to pass argument(the reflector) to the guard as I mentioned in the constructor, now will it be okay to initialize the reflector like this?

```
const reflector:Reflector = new Reflector();
app.useGlobalGuards(new RolesGuard(reflector))
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the official Nest JS fundamentals course, in lecture "54 Protect Routes with Guards", the instructor specifies it is not best practice to create instance of reflector yourself.

A better way to resolve dependencies is to create a common module, and register your guard there. That way, reflector instance is resolved by nest runtime and you can also specify imports array for any other dependencies.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AuthTokenGuard } from './guards/auth-token.guard';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthTokenGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  app.useGlobalGuards(new RolesGuard(new Reflector()));
```

It is working also. Could not find any better solution.

Comment: SulsDotK's answer is the best practice now which is in the [official guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#enable-authentication-globally).

Another way is 

`app.useGlobalGuards(new AuthGuard(app.get(Reflector)));`

Answer (score 1):

Although my answer might not add much value, I just want to re-iterate that is the intended way to get the reflector, this is a quote from NestJS's creator

**kamilmysliwiec**

> When you create instance manually, you can create Reflector by
> yourself:
>
> ```js
> new RoleGuard(new Reflector());
> ```

Source: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/396#issuecomment-363111707

Answer (score 0):

2023, NestJs 9, related problem:

In case you inject request-scoped dependency into the globally registered guard, the reflector will be undefined.

You can solve this issue by resolving such dependencies using `ContextIdFactory` and `moduleRef.resolve()` instead of injecting them normally:

```ts
const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
const contextId = ContextIdFactory.getByRequest(req);
this.moduleRef.registerRequestByContextId(req, contextId);
this.authorizationService = await this.moduleRef.resolve(
  RequestScopedService,
  contextId
);
```

References:

- https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref
- [code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reflector-is-undefined-in-global-guard-with-reque-wp8zav?file=src%2Frights.guard.ts)
- https://discord.com/channels/520622812742811698/1060904277607985172

Answer (score 0):

I had two different versions of `@nestjs/core` installed, `npm ls @nestjs/core` told me which dependencies caused this issue.

After resolving, everything worked as expected.